# How to choose a specific date range?

Tags: sql, date, db2

```
SELECT TYPE, TERMINAL, PERIOD_NUMBER, WEEK, DM FROM 
(SELECT 'ACTUAL' AS TYPE, TERMINAL, PERIOD_NUMBER, "WEEK", SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE = 'REVENUE' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END - CASE WHEN TYPE = 'EXPENSE' THEN TOTAL ELSE 0 END) DM FROM BT_CU_DM_TERMINAL
WHERE TERMINAL NOT IN ('99','88')
GROUP BY TERMINAL, PERIOD_NUMBER, "WEEK"
UNION
SELECT 'BUDGET' AS TYPE, RIGHT(GL_ACCT_ID, 2) TERMINAL, PERIOD_NUMBER, WEEK(CURRENT DATE - 5 DAYS) "WEEK", 
CASE WHEN WEEK(CURRENT DATE - 5 DAYS) IN (40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 53,1,2,3,4,5, 14,15,16,17,18,27,28,29,30,31) THEN BUDGET_AMT/5 ELSE BUDGET_AMT/4 END DM FROM GL_BUDGETS WHERE
FISCAL_YEAR_CODE = '2015' AND GL_ACCT_ID LIKE '01-6999-%'
ORDER BY PERIOD_NUMBER, WEEK, TERMINAL)
```

I am using DB2 and am trying to find an appropriate WHERE clause so that is dynamically pulls for the current week; whenever this statement is used. 
For example we are in week 44; however when next week rolls around I would like it to show for the current week.

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using WHERE WEEK = CURRENT_WEEK but I am getting an error Current_week is not valid in the context where it is used

Comment: This will be vastly easier if you have a calendar table.  Because among other things, there's more than one type of "week"; which one do you want?  ISO year-week ("first week of year" sometimes starts in December of the previous year), Weeks since January 1st (last week is 1 or 2 days), or a "fiscal week", which isn't bound to either?  Note that the first day of a week is culture-dependent (although DB2 really only uses Monday, I think).

Answer (score 0):

The current week can be obtained by `week(current date)`.

Comment: right, unfortunately I am already returning results for week; however I need the current week data to show!

Comment: In the comment above you were asking for "current week". Maybe go back and edit the question to be more to the point, what exactly you are asking for. Do you want to rewrite the query? Do you want to change the entire WHERE clause? ...

Comment: Apologies, I am currently pulling data that shows projected vs budgeted and it is based upon two things: week to date and monthly. I have wrapped my two previous clauses to draw the results. However I want to further specify which week I am using!